# How to configure using arrow key to repeat previous shell commands in Minix

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sh, minix

I am new to Minix. I'm so impressed by the speed of the system. It looks elegant, I like it.

However, I have a question about the shell. In Linux, while using a shell, up and down arrow keys can be used to navigate through previously executed commands. On Minix with the sh shell, I can only get numbers printed out on the screen.

I remember I chose a US-std keyboard when installing. Is there any way to use the arrow keys to navigate through previous commands on Minix?

Answer (score 0):

These days the Minix `sh` should be `ash`; if it doesn't recognize your arrow keys, check `$TERM`.  If it's an older Minix (`ash` came in with Minix 3) then the shell is too primitive to support arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks! I downed and installed it today. It is Minix3. I actually used pkgin to install bash, however, after # bash, i typed # echo $SHELL, it still shows sh. I will check $TERM. What should it be? xterm?

Comment: `$SHELL` isn't your current shell, it's your shell from `/etc/passwd`. You need to change it there (`chsh` command) if you want `bash` to be used as your default shell.